# How to suggest multiple words inside textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, autocomplete

Summary: I'm doing a web app to manage products in a warehouse. So I have a db with list of products and quantities. I have one page for unload products when they are used. On that page I have a textbox in which users write the note on how the product has been used.

Request: when users type inside the textbox I'd like a popup to appear showing products that contains the entered characters. More than 1 products is possible. Also users enters quantity of the used products, so I'd like that my app can update the db with new value.

```
 For example:
    I have a product named "AAA batteries" and I have 10 in stock.
    I also have "9V batteries" 5 in stock.

    User write "Used 3 AAA batteries and 4 9V batteries"
    While typing I'd like popup appear suggesting "AAA batteries" etc.
    Then I'd like to update the db subtracting 3 AAA and 4 9V.
    It's ok to use delimiter characters
    User press a button to save the note (db should be updated at this point)
```

Is this possible? I'm already using the ajax autocomplete extender but it can't do exactly what I want. I did a lot o searches but I can't find the right direction, can you help me? Thanks